# PowerShell Script Asking for Input

Tags: powershell

[image: Enter Values]

The image above is my issue. After I click run with PowerShell it asks for variables meanwhile I have it set in the following code:

```
$name = "Action"
$value = 0x00000001 
New-ItemProperty -Path $f1_key_path
    -Name $name
    -Value $value
    -PropertyType DWORD
```

I was hoping by declaring these variables I would be able to not have to use the terminal to write the inputs into the script. I have more cmdlets like this and they are all asking for input is there any reason why? If so how could I get it to use my variables I declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have parameters on different lines like you have there, the last character on a line (except on the last line) needs to be a backtick (`` ` ``). So your code should look like:

```
$name = "Action"
$value = 0x00000001 
New-ItemProperty -Path $f1_key_path `
    -Name $name `
    -Value $value `
    -PropertyType DWORD
```

Make very sure that there is no space or anything after the backtick. Personally I advise against doing this. I would recommend building a hashtable, and then [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) that hashtable like this:

```
$NewItemParams = @{
    Name = 'Action'
    Value = 0x00000001
    Path = $f1_key_path
    PropertyType = 'DWORD'
}
New-ItemProperty @NewItemParams
```

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful. I was generally confused about the setup for the PowerShell Script I also put everything in one line. It also worked.